# How to choose the second wildcard for a rule depending on the first?

Tags: snakemake

I have two wildcards, the first for a species, the second is basically a counter for each file from a specific species. So I have Cow_A, Cow_B and Pig_A, Pig_B, Pig_C for example (the amount of files varies from species to species)

Now what I want is in the Input to select all files of one species using something like this

```
input: expand("{{species}}_{rep}", rep=count(species))
output: "{species}_combined"
```

How do I tell the input function count to use the current species wildcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a function (or lambda) in the input section:

```py
input:
    lambda wildcards: expand("{species}_{rep}", species=[wildcards.species], rep=get_reps(wildcards.species))
output:
    "{species}_combined"
```

You need to define a function that returns the reps for a species. That may be read from config or you may employ the glob_wildcards function:

```py
def get_reps(species):
    return glob_wildcards(f"{species}_{{rep}}").rep
```

Comment: using glob wildcards is a good idea  to clean up some code :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to make use of a function, either an inputfunction:

```
def inputfunction(wildcards):
    expand("{species}_{rep}", species=wildcards.species, rep=count(species))

input: inputfunction
output: "{species}_combined"
```

Or you can make use of a lambda function:

```
input: lambda wildcards: expand("{species}_{rep}", species=wildcards.species, rep=count(species))
output: "{species}_combined"
```

Comment: The lambda expression was exactly what I needed, also the species should not be expanded ( it is {{species}} on purpose). I couldn't wrap my head around those lambda expressions yet, but this seems surprisingly simple :) Thanks a lot